# Docblock for a class property being ignored

Tags: php, phpdoc

I've been documenting class properties using the `@var` tag but when I run phpdoc to generate the documents it is complaining `No DocBlock was found for property $someProperty`.

For example:

```
class MyClass {
   /**
    * Some property that should be documented
    *
    * @var mixed $someProperty
    */
   protected $someProperty; 

   .
   .
   .

}
```

Comment: That one works here.... Is this an example of _actual_ code that fails to be parsed by phpdoc, or can you give us a bigger example (just cut a copy from your class down until you can remove nothing more without causing either parse errors or the proble to disappear).

Comment: Make the class abstract, change the class name and the property's actual name, add a constructor and an abstract method declaration and you have my class.  I'm getting identical behavior from every class I document properties for though.  I'm wondering if there is something about my phpdoc install thats fubared.

Comment: Could be broken indeed, this just works here (fwiw: phpdoc version 1.4.4, but I am not aware of a lower version where this _doesn't_ work)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the phpdoc install was broken in some way.  Uninstalling then installing clean fixed the error.